# Run program in two supervisor's groups

Tags: supervisord

Suppose I have a [supervisor's](http://supervisord.org/) config file like this:

```
[program:type1_X]
command=my_program_1 X

[program:type1_Y]
command=my_program_1 Y

...

[program:type2_X]
command=my_program_2 X

[program:type2_Y]
command=my_program_2 Y

...

[group:type1]
programs=type1_X,type1_Y

[group:type2]
programs=type2_X,type2_Y

[group:type]
programs:type1_X,type1_Y,type2_X,type2_Y
```

So what I'm dong is defining two types of programs (my_program_(X|Y)) that runs with two sets of different parameters (X&Y). Then I group programs on the type of program they are running (type(X|Y)), and then I have one other group (type) that includes all defined programs above (there could be other unrelated programs in the config file).

The problem with this is, that supervisor will start each program twice since it appears in two different groups. So my question is: is there a way to have one program in multiple groups but only start it once (or however times the program defines itself (via "numprocs"))?

edit: Is there really no one who can help?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the program with a shell script that will create a lock or semaphore to start one or a limited number of instances.

Comment: So you would replace supervisor?

Comment: Depends, if it does not fit the bill, yes. If you needed it for other functionality/reasons, I would adapt it to the current requirements.

Comment: It fits the bill perfectly. So what you are proposing isn't really an answer ...